# Object joining break object alignment on Unity import

Tags: unity

New Blender user here. I'm using Blender to create some game assets. Specifically, I'm modelling pieces in an old application called Realsoft 3D that has the best modelling tools I've ever seen, and importing them into Blender to UV unwrap and texture.

I've created a hex tile object and some tree objects in Realsoft 3D. I import them into Blender, arrange the trees on the tile, join the objects into one, and create UV mappings before exporting.

However, when I export for use in Unity (as a Collada file), the imported object doesn't line up with the world axis. AFAICS the joined object inherits the rotation values of one of the trees rather than the default, vertex-aligned hex tile base.

I've just experimented with the order of object selection prior to joining. Am I correct in thinking that the first object selected before joining is the one defining the joined object's orientation, and as such, as long as I select the hex tile first, everything should be good?

Edit: Okay, so it's actually the last object selected that defines final orientation, I think.

Comment: When joining objects inherit options like origin point, unapplied transforms from the object selected last (active) before joining. Also before exporting it's a good idea to apply transforms (Object mode > Ctrl+A) and set the objects in the scene center as it will be considered as exported asset origin. It would be helpful to see some screenshots of before and after exporting.

Comment: I thought I had screenshots but can't find them. I seem to have fixed the issue; as you say, it's last object selected that defines the final object. For screenshots, just imagine a joined object in Blender imported into Unity where it's 'straight' when imported, but the handles are rotated, so Y isn't up but slightly to the right. I think i have it sorted now. Thanks.